# Закрыть окно через controller

Tags: javafx

Приложение  открывается, в нем кнопка exit , описана в. Fxml и сгенерирован метод в controller не имея доступа к main классу содержашего stage.close() как Правильно закрыть кнопкой приложения. Без system.exit

Answer (score 0):

Приложение завершится, когда все окна закрыты, закрыть окно при клике на собственную кнопку, генерирующую `MouseEvent event` можно получив из него stage:

```
((Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene.getWindow()).close();
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает . А можно пояснить как? Не очень понимаю как я таким образом получил обьекты  из Main класса . А точнее как связывается actionEvent getSource что за сорс я получаю.

Comment: event.getSource возвращает элемент с которым произошло взаимодействие. Вообщем для наших целей подойдет любой элемент в нужном окне. Этот элемент знает на какой сцене он находится, ее и получаем getScene. Аналогично сцена в курсе в каком окне она открыта, получаем getWindow и делаем приведение к Stage. Ну и вызываем нужный нам метод для нашего окна.